# Django: use custom class for request.user?

Tags: django

I've extended Django's default user class like this:

```
class CustomUser(User):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```

But now I want to use that everywhere instead of the default `User` class. In my view methods, I have access to `request.user` but that's an instance of the `User` class. What's the easiest way to make it return a `CustomUser` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also "monkey patch" the existing User model somewhere in your models.py and it should just work. In your code just keep using the original class.

```
User.add_to_class('friends',models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False))
```

Comment: Oh! Wish I knew about that a few days ago. But thanks! I've finished that project so I'm not going to go back and try this right now; I'll just assume this works. Would have been the easiest solution.

Comment: sure, small change though in the syntax (I've used friends=models.ManyToMany) the first time

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can do that exactly, but you can access your CustomUser attributes using the Django user_profile feature.

In your settings.py:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

In your view:

```
user_friends = user.get_profile().friends
```

Check out this [link](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/) for more info.

Comment: I think this requires you to set `User` as a foreign key, rather than inheritance like I'm using...

Comment: This is the preferred way to handle your problem.  It saves you from having to modify existing modules.  Leave django.contrib.auth alone, and make your changes to your own code.

Comment: @jcd to me it's arguable if it's a big deal. "preferred" is a matter of personal opinion and taste, especially for a one-person team.

Comment: `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` has been removed.  `AUTH_USER_MODEL` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

It is all explained [here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/). request.user problem was solved by using an authentication backend. I implemented a custom user according to the author's instructions and have been happy ever since.

Comment: I found that and tried it, but I couldn't seem to get it working. IMO, you shouldn't even have to replace the backend.

Comment: What was the problem? I am comfortable with the custom backend, but if you don't want to use it you can write a middleware, as per suggested in one of the comments to that post.

Comment: This is 'teh win' solution right here.  A small amount of glue code and you never have to worry about it again.  Everywhere in your app gets your custom User model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the quickest solution to your problem would simply be to call `CustomUser.objects.get(user=user)` (this is assuming user is an attribute in your CustomUser model. What I would do is the following:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

So when you get a queryset of CustomUsers, you can filter out the one you want based on using a filter of your user at the request.

Otherwise you can modify the middleware to include CustomUsers instead of users, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that ;)

EDIT: Mark mentioned to me that he would prefer to use inheritence so hes able to use all the custom methods of User, which makes sense and so I found an article to fix this problem nicely.

[Here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) it is.

Comment: The problem with using a foreign key instead of python inheritance is that you don't get access to all the custom methods. Maybe there is a way I can query it instead though...

Comment: Ah, I see what you were talking about. I think this link will provide you with exactly what you're looking for!

http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying that but it doesn't seem to be using my ModelBackend... it's still using the default one, even though I specified `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`...

Comment: `CustomUser.objects.get(user=request.user)` won't work btw, *but* `user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)` seems to do the trick. Not the optimal solution, but Django and me don't seem to be getting along very well at all anyway, so this is nothing new...

Comment: Really, CustomUser.objects.get(user=request.user) didn't work eh... Strange, I definitely use it in work I've done. Does your CustomUser have a user field?

Comment: No, it doesn't... the model I posted in my question is complete (yes, it's only 2 lines).